# Azure Active Directory SSO with MSAL and openID Connect

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I was tasked with writing an ASP.NET website that uses Azure Active Directory. I went with the route of OAuth and OpenID Connect. I am not able to use implicit flow and therefore must set the ResponseType to be code.
Using MSAL code samples I got most of it working but the problem is that all the samples are using a response type that returns tokens. I think I need to do it in 2 separate steps, first get the authorization code and then get the id token. I'm not exactly sure how to do this and would much appreciate some guidance here.

I have a startup class that look like this:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
             new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 Authority = authority,
                 ClientId = clientId,
                 RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                 Scope = "openid profile email offline_access user.readbasic.all", // a basic set of permissions for user sign in & profile access
                 ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
                 ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                 TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                     // In a real application you would use ValidateIssuer = true for additional checks and security.
                     ValidateIssuer = false,
                     NameClaimType = "name",
                 },
                 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                 {
                     AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                     AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                 }
             }); 
    }
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        // Handle any unexpected errors during sign in
        context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
        context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        /*
         The `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` is created and hooked in the `UserTokenCache` used by `IConfidentialClientApplication`.
         At this point, if you inspect `ClaimsPrinciple.Current` you will notice that the Identity is still unauthenticated and it has no claims,
         but `MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache` needs the claims to work properly. Because of this sync problem, we are using the constructor that
         receives `ClaimsPrincipal` as argument and we are getting the claims from the object `AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context`.
         This object contains the property `AuthenticationTicket.Identity`, which is a `ClaimsIdentity`, created from the token received from 
         Azure AD and has a full set of claims.
         */
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClient = GroupManager.Utils.MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication(null);

        // Upon successful sign in, get & cache a token using MSAL
        AuthenticationResult result = await confidentialClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "openid profile email offline_access user.readbasic.all" }, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();       
        
    }
```

How do I take the information from the result's tokens and create a claims identity for the AuthenticationTicket.Identity and access the user info?

Please note that this is an ASP.NET application. Not MVC and not Core.

Answer (score 0):

If you use MSAL, you don't need to handle the `code` yourself. MSAL will return the token to you after you log in interactively, please see:[Overview of Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ca-es/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview).

Before that, you need to take a look at [Add sign-in to Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp),the workflow is:
[image]

Code example please check: https://github.com/AzureAdQuickstarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet

**Update:**

Try to enable ID token

[image]

Comment: All these examples have ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken, in the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions. This gives me the error: 'unsupported_response_type'. Error_Description (may be empty): 'AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application.

Comment: @Dassy Try to enable ID token.That will add the property oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow to the manifest file with the value set to "true".

Comment: Thank you for your comments.Like I said in my question, my IT company is hesitant to use implicit flow for security reasons. Therefore they have specifically turned it off. I need help getting around this issue ASAP.